# Magento 2 - How to sort products by popularity?

Tags: php, sql, magento2

How can I sort products by popularity in Magento 2.2.4 in frontend grid catalog ?

Comment: Ok, for anyone who is trying to do it I found a solution, I will post it as an answer for this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution found:
Just create a new product's attribute for popularity with a range value from 1 to 10 (or whatever you need), then set "Used for Sorting in Product Listing" to YES in the attribute's Storefront Properties section.